# Comportamento Soft Delete Spring Boot Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Gostaria de saber se existe a funcionalidade de soft delete no Hibernate, pois hoje estou fazendo de uma forma que considero gambiarra, algo to tipo:

```
@Entity
@Where(clause="ativo=1")
```

Controller:

```
Rejeicao rej = rejeicaoRepository.findOne(id);
if(rej != null){
    rej.setAtivo(0);
    rejeicaoRepository.save(rej);   
}
```

Se alguém tiver alguma forma melhor de fazer eu agradeço

Comment: Atualmente não tem nativo, não concluído nas versões `RELEASE`: [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-307)

Comment: Concordo nativo não tem mesmo, mas será que tem alguma forma menos "gambiosa" de fazer ?

Comment: Eu uso um repositório base customizado, daí lá gero as *queries* específicas para cada caso. Além disso utilizo alguns metadados nas entidades, como para marcar se ela pode ser de fato deletada (ou não apenas logicamente), etc., mas nunca uso em controllers ou services.